problem when merging (joining) 2 files in R
I have 2 csv files and opened them in R. if I print the first few lines, they would look like the following:
> head(file1)
   X         target_id gene_name
1  1 ENSG00000223972.4   DDX11L1
2  2 ENST00000456328.2   DDX11L1
3  6 ENST00000515242.2   DDX11L1
4 10 ENST00000518655.2   DDX11L1
5 15 ENST00000450305.2   DDX11L1
6 22 ENSG00000227232.4    WASH7P
> 
> 
> head(file2)
          target_id length eff_length est_counts tpm
1 ENST00000632684.1     12         13          0   0
2 ENST00000434970.2      9         10          0   0
3 ENST00000448914.1     13          1          0   0
4 ENST00000415118.1      8          9          0   0
5 ENST00000631435.1     12         13          0   0
6 ENST00000390567.1     20          8          0   0

I am trying to merge (join) them and create something like the following:
target_id   gene_name length eff_length est_counts tpm
ENSG00000000003.10  TSPAN6  0   7   7   2
ENSG00000000005.5   TNMD    1   1   8   3
ENSG00000000419.8   DPM1    2   5   1   4
ENSG00000000457.9   SCYL3   1   6   8   5
ENSG00000000460.12  C1orf112    5   7   4   3
ENSG00000000938.8   FGR 3   8   0   0

but what I am getting looks like this:
target_id       X gene_name length eff_length est_counts tpm
ENSG00000000003.10 2573196    TSPAN6     NA         NA         NA  NA
ENSG00000000005.5 2573172      TNMD     NA         NA         NA  NA
ENSG00000000419.8 2430409      DPM1     NA         NA         NA  NA
ENSG00000000457.9  180498     SCYL3     NA         NA         NA  NA
ENSG00000000460.12  179894  C1orf112     NA         NA         NA  NA
ENSG00000000938.8   45152       FGR     NA         NA         NA  NA

the code I am using in R is:
merged_data <- merge(file1, file2, by = "target_id", all.x = TRUE)

do you know how to fix it?

None of the target_ids are matching, so when using all.x=TRUE it will output all file1 rows including columns from file2, but because non match they're all NA. If you have matches and only want to output those try without all.x or use (the default) all.x=FALSE.

@AndreWildberg : in the gene_name of the file1 there are some repeated rows with different target_id. I would like to keep the same structure when merging file1 and file2. if I do not use all.x=True, I would not get this structure. what would be the solution?

If you want all file1 entries to appear you have to fill the non-matching rows with something. There's no way around this.

You can modify your code slightly
library(dplyr)


file1 <- data.frame(
  target_id = c("ENSG00000000003.10", "ENSG00000000005.5", "ENSG00000000419.8", "ENSG00000000457.9", "ENSG00000000460.12", "ENSG00000000938.8"),
  gene_name = c("TSPAN6", "TNMD", "DPM1", "SCYL3", "C1orf112", "FGR")
)

file2 <- data.frame(
  target_id = c("ENSG00000000003.10", "ENSG00000000005.5", "ENSG00000000419.8", "ENSG00000000457.9", "ENSG00000000460.12", "ENSG00000000938.8"),
  length = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3),
  eff_length = c(7, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  est_counts = c(7, 8, 1, 8, 4, 0),
  tpm = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0)
)


merged_data <- file1 %>%
  inner_join(file2, by = "target_id") %>%
  select(target_id, gene_name, length, eff_length, est_counts, tpm)

print(merged_data)

which will result in
           target_id gene_name length eff_length est_counts tpm
1 ENSG00000000003.10    TSPAN6      0          7          7   2
2  ENSG00000000005.5      TNMD      1          1          8   3
3  ENSG00000000419.8      DPM1      2          5          1   4
4  ENSG00000000457.9     SCYL3      1          6          8   5
5 ENSG00000000460.12  C1orf112      5          7          4   3
6  ENSG00000000938.8       FGR      3          8          0   0
> 


How is this different from merge(file1, file2)?

So, with base you would have done merge(file1, file2, by = "target_id")[, c("target_id", "gene_name", "length", "eff_length", "est_counts", "tpm")]. With dplyr, it is easier and more readable. That's all. So, maybe a simple question of taste.

With your provided input both merge and inner_join give the same output.  The select is completely irrelevant and it doesn't address the question.
